Проблема с авторизацией с привязкой к бд
Пытался сделать авторизацию с привязкой к бд, но почему то он не видит данные в столбцах логина и пароля, и выдаёт null.
    var user = AccEntities.GetContext().Vrachi.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == UsernameTextBox.Text && x.Password == PasswordBox.Password);

if (user == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Пользователь не существует.","Ошибка авторизации.",MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
else
{
    if(user.Categoty == "Админ")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Здравствуйте, Администратор " + user.FIO.Split() + "!");
    }
    else if(user.Categoty == "Врач")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Здравствуйте, Врач " + user.FIO.Split() + "!");
    }
    else if (user.Categoty == "Регистратор")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Здравствуйте, Регистратор " + user.FIO.Split() + "!");
    }
    else { MessageBox.Show("Данные не обнаружины!", "Уведомление", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error); }


Кто "он"? Ну, раз не видит, значит их там нет. Посмотрите напрямую в БД, какие там данные.

user.FIO.Split() - ждём вашего вопроса, почему это выдаёт не то, что хотелось бы.
